# Channel Easements for County: Need help with Query or Python

Tags: python, arcmap, geoprocessing, query

I have a layer for easements for a whole county and need to find each easement either MISSING or having a PART of what the county calls "STW_ARCS." These ARCS are what the county have data on for how much linear footage in each (or not each) easement. 
[image: Image is instructions given].
                   I'm having a very hard time using tools to find these easements as described above.

Comment: What have you tried? You should be able to use Select By Attributes and Summary Statistics.

Comment: I've been using more select by location more than attributes. Did you have something in mind?

Comment: Well it is unclear what you are asking. Could you add a screenshot showing the attribute table and what you want to do? Do you only have one feature class?

Comment: I'm actually not quite sure how to add more than one image on this forum.